# Simplest way to create a JList containing only Strings (Jlist has to be changed at runtime)

Tags: java, runtime, jlist

I tried creating a Jlist in Netbeans by creating a ScrollPane first and then adding a Jlist to that.

Then I went on to fill that JList with some strings and such using defaultlistmodel.add(String a). The first time it displays the items nicely. But now based on user input, I want to clear all the elements in the list model and create a new list.

This is where I start encountering some problems. model.clear() doesn't seem to work nor does jList1.removeAllElements()..

I need to know where I am going wrong?

```
 private void populateList(){

    readFileContents();
    model.clear();
    jScrollPane1.validate();

    for(String str : list){

        model.addElement(str);

    }

    jList1.setModel(model);

}
```

Comment: What is `JList.removeAllElements()`? The method does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to repopulate a `JList`:

```
public class ClearList extends JFrame {

    String[] list1 = new String[] {"AAAA", "BBBB", "CCCC"};
    String[] list2 = new String[] {"1111", "2222", "3333"};
    DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();

    ClearList() {

        JList<String> list = new JList<>(model);
        addElements(list1);

        JButton button = new JButton("Repopulate");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                model.clear();
                addElements(list2);
            }
        });

        getContentPane().add(list);
        getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addElements(String[] elements) {

        for (String s : elements)
            model.addElement(s);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new ClearList();
    }
}
```

You should consider adding `addElements` to a custom class extending `DefaultListModel`, or if you are managing several models, make it take a model too: `addElements(String[] elements, ListModel model)`.

Comment: Thanks. I had made a stupid mistake while coding. I had used an ArrayList to populate my JList and while I was clearing the listmodel, I forgot to clear the ArrayList. Thanks for your help! This is how I did it as well